# PHP preg_match certains characters

Tags: php, preg-match, alphanumeric

I've got the following code which checks if my $_REQUEST['comment'] contains alphanumeric characters plus a few extras like - , ;

Other than alphanumeric, i would like to make sure that the following characters are also valid (including a space): `! " £ $ % & ( ) - _ + = [ ] : ; ' @ # ? . ,`

```
if (!preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-,;]/', $_REQUEST['comment'])) {
    echo "valid characters";
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you sure there will only be comments with Latin charset? Could people write comments in e.g. Russian or Chinese? If that's the case your regex will not work for these languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put them in the character class:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-,;!"£$%&()+=\[\]:\'@#?.]
```

It can be shortened:

```
[^\w\-,;!"£$%&()+=\[\]:\'@#?.]
```

Also, you would add spaces as valid char:

```
[^\w\s\-,;!"£$%&()+=\[\]:\'@#?.]
```